# How to optimize an approximated matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra

[**UPDATING**]

Here is a solution based on the suggestion of professor Bangerth. To describe what I am trying to do, first rewrite the question into
$$\max_X\|(I-\alpha X)^{-1}X\circ AE\|_F^2$$
where $X,A$ still are $n$ by $n$ square matrices, $E$ is a vector with all the elements are one such that $E=(1,\cdots,1)^\top$. According to professor Bangerth's transformation, the objective becomes
$$\max_B\left\|\frac{1}{\alpha}(B-I)\circ AE\right\|_F^2$$
where $B=(I-\alpha X)^{-1}$. Now the gradient of objective with respect to $B$ is
$$\nabla_B\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\text{Tr}(B-I)\circ(AEE^\top A^\top)\circ(B-I)^\top\right)
=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}(B-I)\circ AE(I\circ AE)^\top
$$
By the stochastic gradient descent (SGD) algorithm, $B$ follows
$$B^{t+1} = B^t + \eta \nabla_B$$
So initialize $B$ as $B^0 = (I-\alpha X^0)^{-1}$ for a guess $X^0$, $B$ can keep iterating till convergence.

The constraint of $B$ is the specification of matrix $X$, which is a sparse matrix and each column has and only has one one. To update $X$ for each iteration, compute the objective, denoted by $J$, with the $B^t$ from SGD, find the location of maxima in each row of
$$A + \alpha J$$
then mark the same location in $X$ as one, the rest keeps being zero, this called $X'$. In Python, this can be done by

```
ini  =  np.argmax(A + alpha * J, axis = 1)
X    =  np.zeros([n,n])
X[np.arange(n),ini]  =  1
```

The updated $B'$ can be obtained by $X'$ such that $B'=(I-\alpha X')^{-1}$. We can also put $B'$ into SGD to get $B^{t+1}$, these iterations stop when $\|B'-B^t\|<\epsilon$.

The whole thing can be implemented theoretically and pratically, I think. But I still have one pivotal question:

**How to add the constraint to the objective or express it as a panelty function?**

---

[**OLD**]

Suppose the objective I try to maximize is
$$\max_{X} \|(I - \alpha X)^{-1}XA\|_F$$
where $X$ is the matrix needs to be pinned down, and $\alpha$ is a scalar. **$(I-\alpha X)^{-1}$ is invertible only when $\alpha\neq1$, this has been proven in the following answer by obscurans**. All matrices are $n$ by $n$ square matrices. An extra condition of matrix $X$ is that the vectors $X(:,k)$ for $k=1,\cdots,n$ is selected from identity by the optimization. So $X(:,k)$ is also a standard basis vector and $X$ may have repeated columns.

One possible way to obtain the maxima of the objective is to apply the matrix multiplication via random sampling, where the objective is rewritten as
$$\max_{p_k}\left\| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k}B(:,k)X(k,:)A\right\|_F$$
where $B$ is the inverse and be approximated by Neumann series such that
$$B = (I - \alpha X)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^n (\alpha X)^k$$

I find this method is too complex to implement on numerical calculation. Is there any better way to solve this puzzle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry it’s Frobenius

Comment: When you're saying the vectors are "selected from identity" do you mean (1) $X$ is 0-1 column-stochastic, or (2) $X$ is a permutation matrix? In particular, powers of permutation matrices are easy - just run a cycle decomposition.

Comment: Property (1) is also preserved under powers: each column under multiplication just picks off a different column of the original matrix. So computing $B$ isn't difficult.

Comment: Or do you mean that each column of $X$ is a standard basis vector? If so, can $X$ have repeated columns? Also, while this may be immaterial, is $A$ a square matrix? Or is it tall or fat instead?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, obscurans and user1511. I am sorry I didn't make a clear description. $X$ is a permutation matrix that contains standard basis vectors as its columns, and these columns can be repeated. I don't know whether my thought to solve this question is efficient. And obscurans could you elaborate on the method if you are convenient? I am very kind of new to this topic, thanks!

Comment: @user1551, thanks. $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. My thought is to maximize the value function in Frobenius norm by choosing a $X$, and the selection of $X$ is by random sampling its columns with probability $p_k$ and then compute the mean, which helps me get the maximum value, saying the maxima becomes my target. If I do this by random sampling, all I need   to do is compute at most $n$ probabilities $p_k$ for $k=1,\cdots,n$ and then let the mean of samplings does the rest. I wonder if this is too complexy to implement, or does it cost too much computations?

Comment: Thank you. In normal cases, $n$ will be 200 to 500; while in some specific cases, $n$ is less than 100.

Comment: Other than its size, what can you tell your Readers about the matrix $A$?  Is it a dense real matrix?  A simplified version of the problem can be posed replacing $A$ with a real vector, in which case the multiplicity of solutions $X$ can be more easily visualized.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @hardmath. I post a solution to my question, where $X$ is a sparse has and only has one one in each column, the rest being zero. The solution of choosing $X$ is no long by random sampling, I combined it with SGD algorithm. However, it still has one issue.

Comment: I'm reluctant to make suggestions about solutions.  In the revised problem matrix $A$ is replaced by vector $AE$.  However I think this is not equivalent to the old problem, and presumably a small example would illustrate this.  Since the finding of $X$ (subject to the constraint of exactly one entry $1$ per column, otherwise zero) has finitely many possibilities, existence of a maximum is clear.  Uniqueness of the solution seems doubtful.  You have omitted any explanation of the source of the problem (its motivation) and the parameter $\alpha$ seems to be included as an afterthought.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I know what I'm looking for, there's a much easier proof of the below.

A stochastic matrix models a transition step of a Markov chain. Every state must transition into exactly one other state, probabilistically.

What this means is, the total probability mass must be conserved, and therefore $[1,1,\ldots,1]^T$ is always an eigenvector, of eigenvalue $1$.

But now $I-X$ necessarily has the same eigenvector, of eigenvalue *zero*, and is never invertible!

---

**[Old]** At the very least, you can compute $(I-X)^{-1}$ easily with a cycle decomposition. Note that a permutation matrix is one representation of the permutation group, and all of the group theoretic properties of permutations apply.

In particular, for any $X$, it is guaranteed that for $N=\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)$, that $X^N=I$. The reason: trace the orbit of any particular object as you iterate the permutation. This cycle length must necessarily be between 1 and $n$. So if you run this many powers of the permutation, every single element must have simultaneously returned to its original spot.

Now, you can factor the power series as
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty X^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty X^{Nk}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}X^j\right)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty I\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}X^j\right)$$
and now there's a rather big problem. $I-X$ is *never* invertible!

---

A column-stochastic 0-1 matrix has the same issue. Notice that when multiplying with a power of $X$, a column being a basis vector simply means "take that corresponding column of what I'm multiplying".

Therefore, the generalization is that instead of a permutation, you have a general function $\pi:\{1,\ldots,N\}\rightarrow\{1,\ldots,N\}$.

What doesn't change, is that after $N$ (as above) powers of $X$, *at least one* point must have returned to its original location. Think about tracing the orbits again: you might collapse multiple points into the same location, but eventually they'll be in cycles, and those original points must close their cycles (possibly of length 1).

$I-X$ remains singular.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough proof! I re-edited the question by adding a scalar $\alpha$ to the matrix $X$ to aviod the invertible issue. However, I still have 2 little questions. (1) We do not know the form or the specification of $X$ in advance but choose each column of $X$ by random sampling with probability $p_k$, is cycle decomposition still working under such case? (2) My apology  that this is the first time I meet cycle decomposition, could you possibly give me some reference to help me understand how to compute $(I-X)^{-1}$ with a cycle decomposition? Thanks!

Comment: I had to unwind the edit history of the Question to appreciate your Answer fully.

Comment: @ZubaTupaki I'm interpreting your question as *pick* $X$ to maximize your objective, so for any actual $X$ that you want to calculate it will *be* a permutation, where this decomposition applies. Now with $\alpha$ regularization (which is running extremely close to my own PhD dissertation), you can still use the fact that $X^N$ is identity, hence $\alpha^NX^N$ is a multiple of identity.

Comment: Another way of looking at it, avoiding the use of a global $N$ which could be large in your case, is that permutation matrices can be **block** decomposed into pure cycles, which is a faithful representation of the same concept for an abstract permutation. Notice now that in powers of $X$, each block acts completely independently of the others, so computing the series can be done blockwise. The price is of course you now need to choose a particular $X$.

Comment: Thank you @obscurans. I have updated my question and also presented a solution to the question. However, I still have one issue for this, you can take a look if you are interested.